# Percentile of a range of floating points

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, percentile

I'm writing a function which takes a list of floating point numbers and prints out the 'pth' percentile of the floating points:

```py
from scipy import stats

def print_percentiles(a, p):
    for i in p:
        print('The ', i, 'th percentile is ', stats.scoreatpercentile(a, i), '.', sep='')

print_percentiles([1, 1, 3, 6, 2], [50])
# The 50th percentile is 2.0.

print_percentiles(range(1, 21), [75, 25])
# The 75th percentile is 15.25.
# The 25th percentile is 5.75.
```

I get the correct output for the first test, however when the first argument of the function is a range of numbers (1, 21) the output is incorrect, it should be:

The 75th percentile is 15.0.

The 25th percentile is 5.0.

Why is the function producing the wrong output in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just use the desired `interpolation_method='lower'` as this is not the default one as described in the [documentation](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.scoreatpercentile.html).

```
from scipy import stats

def print_percentiles(a, p):
    for i in p:
        print('The ', i, 'th percentile is ', stats.scoreatpercentile(a, i, interpolation_method='lower'), '.', sep='')

print_percentiles([1, 1, 3, 6, 2], [50])
# The 50th percentile is 2.0.

print_percentiles(range(1, 21), [75, 25])
```

results:

```
The 50th percentile is 2.0.
The 75th percentile is 15.0.
The 25th percentile is 5.0.
```